# Soft-bricking android devices during application development

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android development, Just configured Android Studio for Windows.

I am concerned about using my current Android devices to develop with, I don't have any spare units laying around, and I want to avoid Soft-Bricking my only usable Tablet/Phone.

I've looked around the internet briefly and found that it is possible to Soft-brick units with applications that require Root access. Obviously when downloading something from the App store you are prompted about if it requires Root access. How does this play out with USB development? When I send a test application to my phone from AS will I be prompted with permission level stuff too? Can I tell from AS which permissions need to be accepted on a project-by project basis?

When running an Android Virtual Device on my PC and, if, I Soft-Brick that will a restart fix that? Would I need to re-create the emulator?

Comment: Ok, let's start from the beginning: is your phone/tablet rooted?

Comment: @BartekLipinski no

Comment: Then you won't be able to use the "dangerous" features of applications that require Root access. I don't think you should be worried at all about doing something to your device. It's not really that easy to do anything that a simple reboot won't fix.

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using a physical device for a year now and I've done nothing wrong, you shouldn't worry about ruining something. It's not like something risky to do. The only way you'd risk ruining it is by needed root access, or rooting your device. Other than that, don't worry. It'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I exclusively use my personal phone for testing through android studio. Android adb is very reliable and you shouldnt be worried about bricking a phone. Happy coding!